# javascript file in iphone...?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I want to make a calculator..all the calculation code is given in javascript file..I don't want to do all the calculation again..?can there is any method that can directly call the methods given in javascript  file...?

sample of javascript file is here---

```
function reset() {
D6080One.resetAll();
D6080Multi.resetAll();
IsoOne.resetAll();
IsoMulti.resetAll();
}


/**
 * D6080 Extended One pump
 */

function D6080One() {}

D6080One.fillEquipment = function() {
    document.getElementById("d6080one-equip").options.length = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < nfpa.length; ++i) {
        if(nfpa[i][0] == document.getElementById("d6080one-manu")[document.getElementById("d6080one-manu").selectedIndex].value) {
            document.getElementById("d6080one-equip").options[document.getElementById("d6080one-equip").options.length] = new Option(nfpa[i][1], nfpa[i][1]);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("d6080one-equip").selectedIndex = 0;
}

D6080One.resetAll = function() {
    document.getElementById("d6080one").reset();
    D6080One.fillEquipment();
}

D6080One.resetResults = function() {
    document.getElementById("d6080one-suv").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-sut").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-maxov").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-minot").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-hov").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-lot").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-lov").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-hopt").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-minov").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-maxot").value = "";
    document.getElementById("d6080one-grade").value = "";
}

D6080One.solve = function() {
    var a, b, l1, l2, l3, lt, ltGrade, r, record, result, s, t750;

    document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").value = document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").value.replace(/,/, ".");
    document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").value = document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").value.replace(/,/, ".");

    if(document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").value == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").value)) {
        alert("Please Choose a Highest Operating Temperature!");
        document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").value = "";
        document.getElementById("d6080one-hot").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").value == "" || isNaN(document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").value)) {
        alert("Please Choose a Lowest Start-Up Temperature!");
        document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").value = "";
        document.getElementById("d6080one-lst").focus();
        return false;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < nfpa.length; ++i) {
        if(nfpa[i][0] == document.getElementById("d6080one-manu")[document.getElementById("d6080one-manu").selectedIndex].value
                && nfpa[i][1] == document.getElementById("d6080one-equip")[document.getElementById("d6080one-equip").selectedIndex].value) {
            record = nfpa[i];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "can there is any method that can directly call the methods given in javascript file...?"? Do you mean to know if there is a more structured way of calling the above methods from a single place/object?

Comment: yes i want to call the methods in js file directly..i dont want to write the methods again in objective c program...or any other easy method than this..?

Comment: So you want to call this from obj-c? An iOS native app? not from within a browser?

Comment: yes...from appp...like a click of button not from browser..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Javascript in a small HTML web page.  Put those HTML and Javascript files in your app bundle, and display them inside a hidden UIWebview.  Call your Javascript function using the web view's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method.